# Is playing multiple money cards multiple actions in Monopoly Deal?

Tags: monopoly-deal

Does playing three money cards to your bank counts as an one of your actions or all three of them?

Answer (score 3):

Adding three money cards to your bank counts as all three of your actions.

The rules describe step 2 of the turn as:

> **Play up to 3 cards**
>
> ... Play 3 cards in any combination of the following: ...
>
> A. Put Money/Action cards into your own bank ...
>
> B.Put down properties into your own collection ...
>
> C. Play action cards into the center

Putting down three money cards would count as playing three cards, all three of which fall under category "A" above.